# Assigning a variable in XSL FO foreach statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file which holds the value of a column, I need to pass that as a parameter to my xsl foreach statement. Below is my implementation, But I am not getting the desired result:

**XML**

```
      <PdfPrinter>
      <Reports>
      <Report>
      <CreatedDate>2015-10-07T18:07:45</CreatedDate>
      <LogType>ChangePassword</LogType>
      <LoginID>ADMIN</LoginID>
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <AppVersion></AppVersion>
      <System>OS</System>
      <UserIPAddress>192.168.1.83</UserIPAddress>
      <LoginDate />
      <LogoutDate />
      <Remarks></Remarks>
      </Report>
      <Report>
      <CreatedDate>2015-10-07T18:09:54</CreatedDate>
      <LogType>ChangePassword</LogType>
      <LoginID>SUPERADMIN</LoginID>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <AppVersion></AppVersion>
      <System>OS</System>
      <UserIPAddress>192.168.1.83</UserIPAddress>
      <LoginDate />
      <LogoutDate />
      <Remarks></Remarks>
      </Report>
      <Header>
      <ReportID>AUD002</ReportID>
      <GroupingColumn1>LoginID</GroupingColumn1>
      <PrintedBy>SOS</PrintedBy>
      <PrintedDate>2016-07-22T11:53:59.8826074Z</PrintedDate>
      </Header>
      </Reports>
      </PdfPrinter>
```

**XSLT**

```
//variable declaration
<xsl:key name="Report" match="Report" use="$GroupingColumn" />
<xsl:variable name="GroupingColumn">
<xsl:value-of select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/GroupingColumn1" />
</xsl:variable>

//Usage of the assigned variable 
 <xsl:for-each select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*[local-name() !='$GroupingColumn']">
   <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(4.77)"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

In the XML, GroupingColumn1 may contain any value which i should pass it to my XSL foreach.

```
    **My XSL TABLE**

    <fo:table border-bottom-width="5pt" 
    width="1200pt" border-bottom-color="rgb(0,51,102)">
    <!--table header-->
      <xsl:for-each select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*[local-name() != 'LoginID']">
    <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(4.77)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
     <fo:table-header>
     <fo:table-row height="20.81pt" display-align="center" overflow="hidden">
    <xsl:for-each select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[1]/*[local-name() != 'LoginID']">
    <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border="rgb(0, 0, 0) solid 1pt" padding="2pt">
      <fo:block color="rgb(0,0,0)" text-align="center" font-weight="normal">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
     </fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-header>
   <!--table body-->
   <fo:table-body>
     <xsl:for-each 
   select="PdfPrinter/Reports/Report[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Report', LoginID)[1])]">
     <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="{count(*) - 1}">
      <fo:block><xsl:apply-templates select="LoginID" /></fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  <xsl:for-each select="key('Report', LoginID)">
    <fo:table-row display-align="before">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() != 'LoginID']">
        <fo:table-cell text-align="center" 
        border-top-color="rgb(0, 0, 0)" 
         border-top-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding="2pt">
          <fo:block>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
         </xsl:for-each>
         </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

In the above table, I have hardcoded the column name as LoginID, instead of that i want to pass the variable name and to create the table. I am able to print the GroupingColumn variable but dont know why it is not printing the output.

Comment: You XSL makes no sense against your input XML. Do not try to snip it and think we can understand, Example: your XSL has an xpath "/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/GroupingColumn1", that does not exist anywhere in your XML so it would return nothing, There is no way to diagnose your problem with compete information.

Comment: @KevinBrown: I am implementing level 1 grouping based on the GroupingColumn1 value in the XML, I should be able to pass the GroupingColumn1 value to my XSL as shown in the above snippet. I think this is just variable assignment, if required i will post the full XSLT. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer given by me only works in XSLT 2.0, as in XSLT 1.0 "It is an error for the value of either the use attribute or the match attribute to contain a Variable Reference". (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key)

It is possible in XSLT 1.0, but it won't be very efficient, but try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="GroupingColumn" select="/PdfPrinter/Reports/Header/GroupingColumn1" />

<xsl:template match="/PdfPrinter">
    <table>
        <header>
            <row>
                <cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$GroupingColumn" />
                </cell>
                <xsl:for-each select="Reports/Report[1]/*[local-name() != $GroupingColumn]">
                    <cell>
                      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                    </cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </header>
        <body>
            <xsl:variable name="distinct" select="Reports/Report[not(*[local-name() = $GroupingColumn] = preceding-sibling::Report/*[local-name() = $GroupingColumn])]" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$distinct">
                <xsl:variable name="current-grouping-key" select="*[local-name() = $GroupingColumn]" />
                <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="../Report[*[local-name() = $GroupingColumn] = $current-grouping-key]" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$current-group">
                <row>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <cell rowspan="{count($current-group)}"><xsl:value-of select="$current-grouping-key" /></cell>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="*[local-name() != $GroupingColumn]">
                    <cell>
                      <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </cell>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. slightly modified the code and desired output has come.. Many thanks for helping me out..

Comment: My sincere apologies, the above XSLT is working perfectly. Tested it and modified as per my requirements. Thank you..